# Invite friends from facebook on my application using facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-actionscript-api

I create a application which allow user integration through facebook(connect with facebook).when user sign-in in application , i want to show all facebook friends of sign-in user for invite them to join my application.

In current i am using multi friend selector for invite friends.

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:request-form action="action url"
method="POST"
invite="true"
type="invite"
content=" my message">
<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="true"
bypass="cancel"
cols=3
email_invite="false"
import_external_friends="false"
actiontext="Invite your friend from facebook"/>
</fb:request-form>
</script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

I want to customize mult friend selector 
1 Can change css and show all friend in a single column?
2 can i show disable the friends whose are already connect with my application?

please give your suggestion or if any other option for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `cols` parameter for the number of columns, and use the `exclude_ids` array to, well, exclude the ids you want. It's all here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector

Comment: thanks,  but it not allow to show less then two column, i want to show all friends in single column. One another thing is that, the exclude_ids work perfect but i want to give a link on already connected friends which show a pop up and give option to make a friend on my application.

Comment: I don't think you can fiddle much more with XFBML controls :\

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the URL to which facebook redirect when the friend accept the invitation